# Update jLabel repeatedly

Tags: java, swing

I have a application which reads 100's input files and generate a single CSV. I am looking to display the current file read in a jLabel. How to achieve this?

I just have a single upload button for the user. User will upload all the file names with absolute path. The application reads all the files and generates a csv.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would probably want to use a `SwingWorker` to read all the files. Then in the `SwingWorker` you would `publish` the name of the file currently being read. Then in the `process(...)` method of the `SwingWorker` you update the label with the published value.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Tasks That Have Interim Results](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/interim.html) for more information and a working example of a `SwingWorker`.

The other option is to create a separate Thread to read the files and then in that Thread you invoke `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)` whenever you want to update the label. This is essentially what a SwingWorker does for you in a formal API.

Comment: That helped. Thanks :)